# For URLRewriter tuckey how can I stop processing further rules once a rule matches

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using tomcat with tuckey for URLRewrite. I have few rules in my urlrewrite.xml. How can I make sure that if one of the rule matches ; it stops processing further rules !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer ; for  mention "last=true"
For example:

```
    <rule >
        <from>/kids/(.*)$</from>
        <to type="forward" last="true">/kids/$1.jsp</to>
    </rule>
```